# Splitting an input that doesn't have blank spaces

Tags: java, input

I have an input that looks like this `ABABABAABA`, i want to split the input into single characters and then count the number of occurrences letter "A" and "B". this is what i have so far

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = str.nextLine();

    userInput.split("");
```

What should I do after to count how many occurrences there are of letter "A" and "B"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to split it, simply iterating over it would be enough. Then you can use a map to count the occurrences like this:

```
 Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
 String userInput = str.nextLine();
 Map<Character, Integer> occ = new HashMap<>();
 for(char ch : userInput.toCharArray()) {
  if(!occ.containsKey(ch)) {
    occ.put(ch, 0);
  }
  occ.put(ch, occ.get(ch) + 1);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess i have to look at the maps lesson again.

Answer (score 0):

You would loop through your string and read the character with `[String.charAt(index)'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true). No need to split at all.).

```
int countA = 0;
int countB = 0;

for(int index = 0; index < userInput.length(); index++)
{
    char c = userInput.charAt(index);

    if(c == 'A')
    {
        countA++;
    }
    else if(c == 'B')
    {
        countB++;
    }
    else
    {
        // some other character detected
    }
}
```